# Offset page number when using turn.js with hash.js

Tags: jquery, hash

I am using turn.js and hash.js to create a flipbook that is paginated: [www.professorleonidas.com/livro](http://www.professorleonidas.com/livro)

What I would like is for the page numbers to start after the table of contents, so basically offset the page numbers shown in the hash by 8 (page 9 becomes 1 in the address bar).

I still want the links to work though of course. So http://www.professorleonidas.com/livro/#page/9 goes to the new 9 (not 1).

The script:

```
$('.book').turn({
        // Width

        width:960,

        // Height

        height:600,

        // Elevation

        elevation: 50,

        // Enable gradients

        gradients: true,

        // Auto center this flipbook

        autoCenter: true,

        // Events

        when: {
            turning: function(event, page, view) {

                Hash.go('page/' + page).update();
                //Hash.go('page/' + page).update();

            }}

});
Hash.on('^page\/([0-9]*)$', {
    yep: function(path, parts) {

        var page = parts[1];

        if (page!==undefined) {
            if ($('.book').turn('is'))
                $('.book').turn('page', page);
        }

    },
    nop: function(path) {

        if ($('.book').turn('is'))
            $('.book').turn('page', 1);
    }
});`
```

Hoping someone can give me some guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the page

```
when: {
   turning: function(event, page, view) {


   $(this).turn('page');
   Hash.go('page/' + page).update();
   //Hash.go('page/' + page).update();

}
```